# Filtering out one string from a print statement in python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape a website's many pages for comments. Each page of this website has the comment "[[commentMessage]]". I want to filter out this string so it does not print every time the code runs. I'm very new to python and BeautifulSoup, but I couldn't seems to find this after looking for a bit, though I may be searching for the wrong thing. Any suggestions? My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('website url').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
comments = soup.find_all("div", class_="commentMessage")
for element in comments:
    print element.find("span").get_text()
```

All of the comments are in spans within divs of the class commentMessage, including the unnecessary comment "[[commentMessage]]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple if should do

```
for element in comments:
    text = element.find("span").get_text()
    if "[[commentMessage]]" not in text:
        print text
```

Comment: After learning javascript for a while, python seems too straightforward! That did the trick, thanks Bahrom!

Comment: Yeah, python's great :D @Vurolock